# Windows Registry Cleaner

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

Wants to integrate windows registry cleaner in my .NET project.

- .NET Project has **Targeted framework .NET Framework 4.5** & **Platform target : Any CPU**
- I have used ScanX Registry Cleaner  [Project Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301890/ScanX-Creating-a-Registry-Cleaner)

The Scanning done by Registry Cleaner is perfectly fine But when try to fix Registry by cleaning the registry faulty entries using the Application then my .Net application which is using ScanX Registry Cleaner DLL mostly getting crashed (Mostly when tring to delete large number of entries & mostly in x64 based architecture)

Error which I am getting is fetched from event logs is

```
Faulting application name: XYZ.exe, version: 12.0.21005.1, time stamp: 0x524fac12
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17031, time stamp: 0x530895af
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f8c9c
Faulting process id: 0x13a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d166f6ee793b7f
Faulting application path: C:\XYZ.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 9e30bb27-d2ea-11e5-8253-70f395c9fb29
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Can Anyone help me in resolving this error.

Or

Please suggest any open source Registry cleaner which can be easily integrated in my Project so it works fine with both reqirements **Targeted framework .NET Framework 4.5** & **Platform target : Any CPU**

Comment: Unless you fully understand that code base, I don't think it would be a good move to integrate it with your code. The exception code shows a native error, which would take much more efforts to troubleshoot.

Comment: 0xc0000374 is very nasty, thrown when a heap is corrupted.  Pretty typical of Codeproject.com code, it only ever works when the sun is shining and you've got the wind in your back.  Finding the pinvoke declaration bug is ... character-building, certainly best to move to the next project when it fails this nastily.

Comment: Thanks for your comments it is working fine in platform target x86 but having some dll problem in x64. Can you suggest any alternatives.